# Pytorch Increase dimension size

Tags: pytorch, tensor

Say I have a tensor of size (4,4,4,4), how can I make a tensor of size (4,4,4,5) such that the newly added entries are 1s?

i.e what's the proper way to do the following?

```py
#given a tensor points of some size
pshape = list(points.size())
pshape[-1] = 1
z = torch.ones(pshape)
return torch.cat((points, z), -1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no special way to do this for non-singleton dimensions. So your solution seems like the proper way to me.

Alternatively, what would work here is:

```py
#given a tensor points of some size
pshape = list(points.size())
pshape[-1] += 1
z = torch.ones(pshape)
z[..., 0:-1] = points
```

On my machine, your code is slightly faster for small tensors while my suggestion is slightly faster for larger tensors. The difference in both cases is marginal though.